# Selenium WebDriver with C#: select item from drop-down menu (doesn't work in IE)

Tags: c#, selenium

It's needed to select the second item from the drop-down menu that is hidden by default. The problem it that it works fine in Fire Fox 41 browser but not in Internet Explorer 11. I'm using Selenium Web Driver with C#, nUnit in Visual Studio 2010. Tests are executed on remote VM with Selenium Server and IEDriver.

HTML looks like:

```
<ul id="CVC" class="buttonMenu" style="visibility: hidden; left: 183px;">
  <li class="menuItem">First</li>
  <li class="menuItem">Second</li>
  <li class="menuItem">Third</li>
</ul>
```

I have C# code that works only in FireFox:

```
var menu = wd.FindElement(By.Id("CVC"));
var menuLi = menu.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
menuLi[1].Click();
wd.FindElement(By.Id("TITLE")).SendKeys("blabla"); //continue to work with appeared pop-up 
wd.FindElement(By.Id("CVC_OK")).Click();
```

When I run test in Internet Explorer an error appears:

```
Test Name:  Bookmark
Test FullName:  EEE.Tests.BT.BB
Test Source:    d:\Selenium\Automation\EEEAutomation\EEEAutomation\Tests\BT.cs : line 19
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:39.319

Result Message: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 35 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'wkqacl0801', ip: '10.101.6.104', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:39901/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 6f09c88a-bd73-4cab-9312-0587c8345023
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at EEE.Tests.SubTests.CreateBBSubTest.Execute(IWebDriver wd) in d:\Selenium\Automation\EEEAutomation\EEEAutomation\Tests\SubTests\CreateBBSubTest.cs:line 103
at EEE.Tests.BT.BB() in d:\Selenium\Automation\EEEAutomation\EEEAutomation\Tests\BT.cs:line 54
```

Does anyone know how to make it worked in Internet Explorer 11?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if IE should be considered as a real browser. In any case I reread your problem, it seems that you expect IE to work like a browser on click event. In that case you might want to help it along :

```
using (var wd = new InternetExplorerDriver(
  new InternetExplorerOptions {EnableNativeEvents = false}))
{
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Earlier when I tried to use SelectElement I saw an error:

OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException : Element should have been select but was ul

So, looks like it will not work with <ul> and <li>

Comment: When I use "var result", VS shows an error: "Cannot assign void to an implicity-typed local variable"

So I used without it: wd.FindElement(By.Id("CVC")).FindElement(By.CssSelector("option[value='1']")).Click();

But received an error:
"OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with css selector == option[value=''1"]"

Comment: As expected, wd.FindElement(By.Id("CVC")).FindElements(By.TagName("li"))[1].Select(); works well in Fire Fox browser. When switched to IE received an error: "OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNonVisibleException: Cannot click on element".

Comment: Sorry for the late response. When I used native events = false, the error was still there. An example: var desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("nativeEvents", false);
                    return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(Settings.Default.RemoteUrl),
                    desiredCapabilities);
But after all I was able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution by using JavaScript. I'm not sure that this is the best solution but at least it works not only in FF, but also in IE browser:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)wd).ExecuteScript("$('#CVC li:eq(1)').click()");
wd.FindElement(By.Id("TITLE")).Clear();
wd.FindElement(By.Id("TITLE")).SendKeys("blabla");
wd.FindElement(By.Id("CVC_OK")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("IdOfControl")).SendKeys(value);
```